# Clip.stop() freeze for few seconds

Tags: java, scala, audio, clip

I have a class Sample and Clip inside, written in Java. I'm playing it in loop:

```
public void play() {
  clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
```

I have also a stop method:

```
public void stop() {
  clip.stop();
}
```

and I want to stop it, when the new Sample instance is initialized (and starts to play) using Scala.

```
def setSample = {
  if (sample != null) {
    sample.stop
  }
  sample = new Sample(track, this)
  if (isPlay == true) {
    sample.play()
  }
}
```

The problem is, that clip.stop() hangs up for few seconds, so the next one isn't played immediately, as I expected. What can I do with that? And why it occurs?

//edit

I tried to use close() method and open clip again before new loop(). The same effect.

Comment: It's best to copy'n'paste compiling code and/or tag with the appropriate language(s). (The last bit looks like Scala.)

Comment: when was 'def' shown above added to Java? in JDK 7.0? that is news to me, I have been away from Java for sometime. Things sure have changed.

Comment: I'm sorry for that:D. The Sample class is written in Java, I'm using it in Scala controller:).

Comment: Are you sure it's "stop" that's hanging rather than "new Sample"? Also, you can just write "if(isPlay)", you don't need "if (isPlay == true)".

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I was printing log just before and after stop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java/sound expert just did some spike previously. According to my tests and the literature the Java Sound API on Windows has some limitations. Hence if you are on Windows you may give ASIO a try to get a low latency playback solution. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_stream_input_output, specifically you will need the ASIO4ALL driver and the JAsioHost Java wrapper.

Comment: I use it in Linux, there is no ASIO. But I don't think latency is a problem. Sound plays just after clip.loop.